# Symfony access folder image in web directory

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony to build a site, and I have a little problem. My images are stored in /web/images/ and I am wondering how I can use this php function glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); to get the list of the files. Actually, it returns an empty array.

Thanks in advance. Here is the code I am using directly from the controller :

```
$imagesDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$json=json_encode($images);
```

Comment: First make sure `$imagesDir` is actually the images directory because I don't think you are looking in the right place.

Comment: Actually it is the images directory, because in my twig files, when I make this <img src="{{ asset('images/7.jpg') }}">, it is the same directory and that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$imagesDir` does not have a trailing slash, `glob()` doesn't add it it just searches for files with name `images*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}'`, change to:

```
$imagesDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/images/';
$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$json=json_encode($images);
```

and it should work.

Comment: Your answer makes sense but isn't it more because in his case `$imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}'` will give something like `dir/imagedir*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}` as a pattern?